# Not Inputting values for certain parameters and working for certain parameters in Arcgis 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, parameters

I am running Python code in ArcGIS Toolbox, inputting 13 parameters. I have used GetParameterAsText(index) function to do it. However it takes values up to 8 parameters properly and the 13th parameter. In between it just inputs blanks even though the input is given.

This is what it shows halfway into the program:

[image]

The code lines where it takes values are (These have several code lines between them):

```
path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
pourpoint = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
dem = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
threshold = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
p2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
landuse = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
o = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
arcpy.AddMessage("99.o")
arcpy.AddMessage(o)
arcpy.AddMessage("100")
arcpy.AddMessage(type(o))#works well till here
pgnm = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
demarc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)
arcpy.AddMessage("106")
arcpy.AddMessage(pgnm)
arcpy.AddMessage("108")
arcpy.AddMessage(demarc)
pgname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)
arcpy.AddMessage("130")
arcpy.AddMessage(pgname)
haveopenvel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9)
arcpy.AddMessage("147.haveopenvel:")
arcpy.AddMessage(haveopenvel)
arcpy.AddMessage("148")
arcpy.AddMessage(type(haveopenvel))
```

and so on.... The only reason 9 and 10 is toppled is cause I was trying out if changing their sequence works. 9 then 10 didn't work either. This is how it looks from the toolbox script:

[image]

But as can be seen from the first image, only till 91.44 value it is taking properly. Others are blank.
Is this a bug?

Also the types are these:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact release of ArcGIS in use.

Comment: 10.2 is *ancient*, and had two minor releases and scores of patches before it was retired. If you have this issue with a clean 10.2.2 or a fully patched 10.2.2 I'd be surprised.

Comment: No sign of this in 10.7.1 (which technically isn't even the current release)